# vuejs render images dynamically

Tags: vuejs2

I'm creating sort of a chatbot. I have an user image and sometimes the content of a message is also an image.

also good to know, the userimage is a static image in assets. the image as content is always a base64 image that is uplaoded before

left the styleblock out on purpose!

problem: vuejs ignores the v-bind.

```
<template>
<div class='chat-wrapper' id="chat-wrapper">
<div v-html = "messages"></div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data: {
      messages:"",
      imageData: ""  // we will store base64 format of image in this string
    },
    methods: {
      checkImage() {
        this.imageData =localStorage["image"]
      },
      startBlock(){
        let html = `   <div class='chat-message chat-message-sender'>
      <img class='chat-image chat-image-default' v-bind:src='./../assets/user.jpg' />
      <div class='chat-message-wrapper'>
        <div class='chat-message-content'>
          <img v-bind:src="imageData" class="startImage">
          <p>Check this image please</p>
        </div>
        <div class='chat-details'>
          <span class='chat-message-localisation font-size-small'>Time</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`
        this.messages = html;
        console.log(html)
      }
    },
      beforeMount(){
        this.checkImage();
        this.startBlock();
      },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean ignore? Do you see a specific error or is the image just not displayed?

Comment: it's just not displayed. in imagedata it litterally displays "imageData",

Comment: I see. If my understanding is correct these [two](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/267) [links](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/42) might be what you need.

Comment: Is `imageData` a complete and valid base64 string? `<img :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData">`

Comment: @LarsBeck yes, i tried it with multiple online decoders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a template String (enclose some string in backticks) and you want some variable to render its value and not its name, you need to write the code accordingly.

Try something like {{imageData}}:

```
   <div class='chat-message chat-message-sender'>
      <img class='chat-image chat-image-default' v-bind:src='./../assets/user.jpg' />
      <div class='chat-message-wrapper'>
        <div class='chat-message-content'>
          <img v-bind:src="{{imageData}}" class="startImage">
          <p>Check this image please</p>
        </div>
        <div class='chat-details'>
          <span class='chat-message-localisation font-size-small'>Time</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```